# IOS file path spaces being split when passed to a library method

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, unix

I have been given a static library to work with that accepts arguments as a space delimited char.

**Method in library**

```
int saveFile(char* param);
```

I am passing it the Documents file path to save to

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
std::string str = [documentsDirectory cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
const char * filePath = str.c_str();
char pa[1024];
pa[0] = 0;
strcat(pa, filePath);
saveFile(pa);
```

My problem is that the IOS file path has spaces in it and this causes the library to split the  path in those places. I have tried escaping the spaces with a "\" and of course, placing the path in quotes does not work in this instance. For example below...

```
/Users/bigbadowl/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/649D2EEB-8C88-42C7-9A74-21629570B1D0/Documents
```

Would be split in to

```
/Users/bigbadowl/Library/Application
Support/iPhone
Simulator/5.1/Applications/649D2EEB-8C88-42C7-9A74-21629570B1D0/Documents
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _split the path_? Where are the three split strings stored?

Comment: It's a fundamental fault with the library, everything with a space gets split. I've managed to get my hands on the source code and changed it to split on a comma instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be replacing the spaces in the original string with an unlikely-to-be-used character (such as `#`), perform the library manipulations, and then revert all the occurrences of this character back to spaces. Something along the lines of:

```
// ...
std::replace(str .begin(), str .end(), ' ', '#');  // Replace spaces with #
const char * filePath = str.c_str();
char pa[1024] = {0};
strcat(pa, str.c_str());
std::replace(str .begin(), str .end(), '#', ' ');  // Replace # with spaces
// ...
```

Of course, you won't get the desired behavior if the original string contains this character. You could always test this and select another character, so this shouldn't be a problem, though.

Comment: This is the closest answer, as per my comments above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this will only be a problem with the simulator. If you can't make changes to saveFile, then you may need to see if you can cheat the simulator.

As a test, see if you can create a symlink to `/Users/bigbadowl/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` in `/Users/bigbadowl/` named `iphonesim`. Then replace `Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` with `iphonesim`.

You will end up with the path `/Users/bigbadowl/iphonesim/5.1/Applications/649D2EEB-8C88-42C7-9A74-21629570B1D0/Documents` with no spaces. See if `saveFile()` can work with that.

Best of luck.